# Using method to create function? The details explanation?

Tags: scala

```
def first[A] :Tuple2[A,_] => A  = ( pair :Tuple2[A,_] ) => pair._1
val name = first( ("Anna", 23) )
```

"If you take a closer look at line 2, what you see here is a method call which returns a newly created function of type Tuple2[String,Any] => String (since the compiler kicks in and infers the needed type for applying to person). Although the whole expression looks like an ordinary method call, it’s in fact a method call (to a factory method without any parameter) and a function call which follows afterwards. " -- this is the explanation of the above code.

I am not able to reason about the first step of the above process (the process creating a function object). Can someone write out a "human compiler" procedure explicitly?

EDIT: I think the fully expanded logic for line 2 should be the following two lines

```
val firstAsFunc= first[String]; 
val name = firstAsFunc(("Anna", 23))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure to break it down further. Here's what I can think of -- I hope you get it, or that someone else is feeling more clever than I.

```
scala> val func = first[String] // method call
func: Tuple2[String, _] => String = <function1>

scala> val name = func( ("Anna", 23) )
name: String = Anna
```

The problem with the above is that `func` is really a getter -- a method call itself -- so I'm hardly changing anything.

**EDIT**

I'm not sure what you mean by *formal* parameter. The method `first` doesn't have value parameters, just type parameters. Trying to pass a value parameter to it would be a syntactical error.

Comment: Nice answer! Why do you use `val func` instead of `def func`?

Comment: @ChrisJamesC - Because Daniel is pointing out that a _function object_ is returned, so you can simply store that function object for later use.  If you used `def func`, you'd make a new call (to `first`) to create a new function object each time `func` was used.

Comment: Chris, nice answer! If we follow your code, I tested

-- "scala> (name).isInstanceOf[Function1[Tuple2[_,_],_]]"

-- "scala>  (name).isInstanceOf[Function1[Tuple2[String,_],String]]"

Both are true

Answer (score 3):

When you say

```
(pair: Tuple2[A,_]) => pair._1
```

the compiler decides that you are actually saying

```
new Function1[Tuple2[A,_], A] {
  def apply(pair: Tuple2[A,_]) = pair._1
}
```

That is, the `first` method creates a new object (of type `Function1`) with a method called `apply` which then is transparently called when you say `first(...)`.  (You would get the same thing if you wrote `first.apply(...)`.)

(Note: `Tuple2[A,_]` can itself be abbreviated `(A,_)`.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure that I understand which bit of the process you're asking about - are you asking about what a function object *is*? I'll answer that question on the assumption that it is :-)

A function object is an object that derives from one of the FunctionN (`Function0`, `Function1` etc.) traits and implements an `apply` method. So your example could be rewritten:

```
scala> def first[A]: Tuple2[A, _] => A = new Function1[Tuple2[A, _], A] { def apply(pair: Tuple2[A, _]) = pair._1 }
first: [A]=> Tuple2[A, _] => A

scala> val name = first( ("Anna", 23) )
name: java.lang.String = Anna
```

You can see that a function is actually an instance of FunctionN like so:

```
scala> def foo(x: Int, y: Double): String = "x = "+ x.toString +", "+ y.toString
foo: (x: Int, y: Double)String

scala> (foo _).isInstanceOf[Function2[_, _, _]]
res1: Boolean = true
```

Comment: I was asking what is the formal parameter for method first.

Answer (score 0):

> If you take a closer look at line 2, what you see here is a method call which returns a newly created function of type `Tuple2[String,Any] => String`

This explanation is wrong. Line 2 does not "return a newly created function". The function is created on line 1, as explained by Rex Kerr.

> Although the whole expression [on line 2] looks like an ordinary method call, it’s in fact a method call (to a factory method without any parameter) and a function call which follows afterwards.

I don't believe this is true; there is no hidden factory method going on, because the `Function1` object has already been created on line 1.

> One of the questions I was asking what is the formal parameter for method first.

See [Wikipedia > Parameter # Computer Science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_parameter#Computer_science)

Comment: This is incorrect. Because `first` is a `def`, no function is created on its definition. Instead, every time `first` is called (such as line 2), a new anonymous function is created. If you have any doubts, try out `first eq first`.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral is this true of all `def`s? Any reference to a `def`'d thing actually desugars to a factory method call? Can you point me to some official Scala docs that explain this in detail?

Comment: Any time you use an identifier which is a `def` causes the body of the `def` to be executed. An anonymous function literal (`x => f(x)`) is an instantiation of an object, so it will create a new object each time it is called. If you insert side effects into the function, you can observe the effects better.